# SQL subquery with (from) aliases

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, alias

I need help with subquery in select clause. I have tables: EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_GROUP) and ACTIVITIES (ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_STATUS, EMPLOYEE_ID). I need to select some activieties, for employees from 'W' Group.

Unfortunately i can't use CREATE TABLE/VIEW function, so i've tried this, but it's not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

TB1.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'START' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 1) AS FIRST_START,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'START' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2) AS SECOND_START,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'STOP' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 1) AS FIRST_STOP,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'STOP' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2) AS SECOND_STOP

FROM( 

     SELECT DISTINCT

     A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,        
     B.ACTIVITY_DATE,
     B.ACTIVITY_STATUS,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,B.ACTIVITY_STATUS 
       ORDER BY B.ACTIVITY_DATE ASC) ACTIVITY_NUMBER

     FROM 
     (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_GROUP ='W')  A

     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES  WHERE ACTIVITY_STATUS IN ('START','STOP','PAUSE') )B
      ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID

  ) TB1
```

Do you know any function, which i can use to select data from table with alias?

Comment: Are you tried CTE(Common table expression)??

Comment: Common table expressions are called Subquery factoring in Oracle documentation. At least they were the last time I read some Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your version of Oracle supports it, but you'll either have to define TB1 as a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
WITH TB1 AS ( 

     SELECT DISTINCT

     A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,        
     B.ACTIVITY_DATE,
     B.ACTIVITY_STATUS,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,B.ACTIVITY_STATUS 
       ORDER BY B.ACTIVITY_DATE ASC) ACTIVITY_NUMBER

     FROM 
     (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_GROUP ='W')  A

     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES  WHERE ACTIVITY_STATUS IN ('START','STOP','PAUSE') )B
      ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID

  )
SELECT DISTINCT

TB1.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'START' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 1) AS FIRST_START,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'START' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2) AS SECOND_START,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'STOP' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 1) AS FIRST_STOP,
(SELECT TB1.ACTIVITY_DATE FROM TB1 
WHERE TB1.ACTIVITY_STATUS = 'STOP' AND TB1.ACTIVITY_NUMBER = 2) AS SECOND_STOP

FROM TB1
```

Or, the old-fashioned way is copy-paste the definition for each instance of "TB1". (Yes, really, this is how we used to do it.)